# Character Attributes ncurses

Tags: c++, curses

I'm trying to check a character's attributes(color)(at a given position)  using curses.h . Is this possible? I found this but I don't know if it is what I need and how to use that parameters(A_ATTRIBUTES, A_COLOR etc): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0629/6j9vjcnte/index.html
Thanks

Comment: The reference you link to mentions *bit-masks*. Do you know anything about *masking* and the bitwise operators? If not then start by [finding a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about it. Then you should hopefully know what to do.

Comment: Do you know if it is another way without using bitwise operators?

Comment: No it's not possible to do bitwise masking without using any bitwise operators.

Comment: Ok. Thanks  a lot

Comment: Regarding the *call* used, that's pointing to Solaris, which has two (or one-and-a-half) implementations of curses.  With X/Open curses, there's also `in_wch` to consider.  But see the Oracle documentation, which places some restrictions on how the color can be stored/retrieved.